# Difficulty with making a header file for C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a header file called **hippiewh**. However, I have been running into some problems.

here's the code for the header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef hippiewh_h
#define hippiewh_h

int askInt(string prompt)
{
    int var_int;
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> var_int;
    return var_int;
}

#endif
```

there are functions like that one for every data type. string, float, and so on.

I can't get this header file working with the online IDE and compiler at [Compilr.com](http://www.compilr.com)

The error i'm getting is:

```
hippiewh.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: hippiewh.h: No such file or directory

Comment: You should not put `using namespace` in a header. Just write the namespace qualifiers.

Comment: Um... what are namespace qualifiers? Besides, I need to put using namespace std; in my header, because i'm using a function from <iostream>, and I don't want my header to use an deprecated file extension.

Comment: You should put everything inside your header's guard. And put `using namespace` inside your functions or just type `std::` otherwise anybody using your header will mix the content of the `std` namespace with his code.

Comment: Ugo, You're right. Denis, NO. #pragma has some serious problems with portability. No way i'm using it.

Comment: The error is elsewhere.
Can you show us the code where you include this file.

Comment: What a lot of text for a simple file not found problem. Why don't you cut out all the extraneous stuff and show us how you included the file.

Comment: -1 for beating around the bush and not focusing on the error message.

Comment: You can also define template<class T> T ask(string prompt) ... It makes your code easier to maintain.

Comment: No, you do not need to use `using namespace` to use namespace members. That's just a shortcut you shouldn't use in header files. Just replace `cin` by `std::cin` and `cout` by `std::cout` to qualify the std namespace. A `using namespace` directive in a header file will apply to **all** header files that are included after it as well as the C++ file it's being included into, which the authors of those might not have wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew, I bet you didn't write the include like this `#include "hippiewh.h"`.

and you did it like this `#include <hippiewh.h>` which is wrong for your own created header files.

If you put all the code here we could help you

Comment: My guess is that he did `#include <hippiewh.h>`

Comment: Yeah that is my guess as well :) it cool to think like an oracle

Answer (score 0):

It should work without hassle :/
You must include the file this way

```
#include "hippiewh.h"
```